# How to wrap text typed with 'typed.js' ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typed.js

I'm building a web app with React that generates random movie quotes...
[image: Here is a preview of the web app]

The problem arises when the quote is too long and it overflows outside the parent div...
I've tried altering the css with display flex and flex-wrap set to wrap. It does't work.
Here is my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import Typed from 'typed.js';
import './App.css';
import quotes from './quotes.json';

const random_quote = () => {
  const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);
  let selected_quote = quotes[rand].quote + ' - ' + quotes[rand].movie;
  return selected_quote;
}

const TypedQuote = () => {
    // Create reference to store the DOM element containing the animation
    const el = React.useRef(null);
  // Create reference to store the Typed instance itself
    const typed = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const options = {
        strings: [
        random_quote(),
      ],
      typeSpeed: 30,
      backSpeed: 50,
    };
    
    // elRef refers to the <span> rendered below
    typed.current = new Typed(el.current, options);
    
    return () => {
      // Make sure to destroy Typed instance during cleanup
      // to prevent memory leaks
      typed.current.destroy();
    }
  }, [])

  return (
      <div className="type-wrap">
        <span style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre' }} ref={el} />
      </div>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='background' id='background'>
        <div className='quote-box'>
          <TypedQuote />
        </div>

        <button onClick={random_quote}>New Quote</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have this idea where I could implement a function that adds '\n' after like 10 words or like maybe after a '.' or ',' (I could implement some logic here). But this seems like a longshot. Is there a fancier way to do this?? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the property below on the parent container.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

or the below if you want to break words as well

```
word-break: break-all;
```